# How to make header height relative to (tab) content height?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hard to explain what i need so i added a image the make things more clear:

**Example: See the image Below**

[image]

I'm building a website with tabbed content on a single page. I want my header and content height to get bigger and smaller when there is more or less content with a total page height that does nog get bigger then 100% When the content is smaller than maximum content size i want the header to become bigger/animate slide down.

How can i make the header and content resize relative to each other and tabbed content size?

Please see the above image for a more clear explanation.

Comment: this may be a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/vlrprbttst/rR7Uu/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @vlrprbttst's fiddle, this is more or less what you need:

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rR7Uu/5/)

## css

```
:root, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.cont {
    background:black;
}
.wrap { height:100%;}
#header {
    height:75%;
    background:red;
}
#content {
    height:25%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background:tan;
}
#tabbed.dynamic-height {
    background:violet;
    max-height:80%;    
}
```

## Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(setHeights);
 setHeights()   
});

  function setHeights() {
 $(".wrap").height($(window).height()-$("#tabbed").height()); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, its a great step in the right direction. But i need the tabbed content inside #content div. The header background and the content background together fill the whole page. So i need the total content size and header to me relative to each other. Inside the content there will be tabbed content.

Sorry, Your solution was great, my question was'nt clear :-)

Comment: you want the tabbed content inside content and aligned to the bottom of the container?

Comment: Yes, thats what i want, i managed to do that. Problem is the tabbed content must scroll when larger then 60% of window and most heights are relative, the content height does not return the same height as tabbed content (0%). So unless i hardcode the height of content in css, this wont work for me. How do i get the content height to return the same heigth as de tabbed content (a (grand)child div). And if that works, how do i the heights to change when i use another tab with diffrent height? 

question is getting more and more complex, sorry about that

Comment: Almost,i need the content height to be the same height as the tabbed content. So content height = tabbed content height + some padding. Header height = 100% - content height